# How to make regex pattern static?

Tags: java, static, variable-declaration

When I try to make static pattern variable I receive an error: *Modifier 'static' not allowed here*. I can't see any reasons, why it doesn't work. Do you have any ideas?

This is how I try to do it:

```
static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9:?;!]");
```

Comment: Not enough information.  I'm guessing you have this declaration inside of a method instead of as a class member variable. You should also add a "final" keyword to declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must place static field declarations **inside a class**, but **outside of method bodies**.